# Titanium Studio not working on MacOS 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: java, macos, titanium, appcelerator, osx-yosemite

I've upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite 10.10 and i get the following error when i try launch Titanium Studio:

The JVM shared library "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I installed Java for OS X 2014-001 from this link:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

It worked.